# Messed up page in Dotnetnuke

Tags: header, tags, dotnetnuke

I installed DNN on my system bout 2 days ago and was playing with the functionality a bit.

Now i seemed to have created a mess which i cannot resolve so was hoping some DNN expert could help on the same.

While created page header tags i accidentally  entered some wrongly formated tags in the text box and saved it. Now the page does not render properly nor does it allow me to change those tags as the page button is not clickable.

Ideally i would need to go to page>page settings and change the page header tags but i cannot click the damn button. This is happening only on one page. How can i resolve this. Tried looking into the Database but do not know which table saves the "page header tags".

Im running DNN 6.01.01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one field called "PageHeadText" in the dbo.Tabs table. Please check it out. Thanks.